# php artisan not responding after upgrading laravel 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

`php artisan` not responding after upgrading laravel 5.1 to 5.2.

I followed the upgrade guide here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade

Even `composer update` gives an error at

```
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
Could not open input file: artisan
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Check your Laravel log in `storage/logs` - there should be additionaly information there. Sure `artisan` is there?

Comment: Nothing is logging. I cleared the log and tried again. Laravel.log is just empty

Comment: Have a look in the generated folder and delete the compiled helper files or test by removing them and try again. This advice worked for me when it was missing after update. Also remove the clear compiled from your composer.json for the first time after update. Seems the artisan changed (not had time since yesterday to see what)

Comment: were you able to figure this out, I'm having this exact issue? Thanks.

Comment: @JustLearninThisStuff The post is too old, I forgot how I solved it. I think I removed the vendor folder and done composer install